# Determine $n$ so that manifold is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: differential-topology

I just started studying smooth manifolds. The definition of a topological manifold requires a topological space to be locally Euclidean: homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I know some examples, like how a 2-sphere is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. In this case we have an intuitive notion of why $n=2$.

Question: for a general topological space, how do we know what $n$ to choose?

Comment: Perhaps "Lebesgue covering dimension" is a place to start?

Comment: @Eric Almost certainly not, since general topology is much messier than manifold topology.  If you have access to a description of arbitrary open sets you can surely just check whether there are sufficiently small Euclidean sets, and of what dimension.

Comment: I think you can first to look what does its open set look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the assumption will state that a manifold is $n$-dimensional.
In other cases, it will state that the manifold is given by level sets, or by gluing together other manifolds,
and should still usually be clear which $n$ to choose. You mention the sphere as a clear example. Another example that is easy is the projective space, or the graph of a continuous function.